# non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type int to std::byte

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, clang

Почему в следующем коде нет ошибок компиляции, но `clang-tidy` выдаёт ошибку? Компилирую с помощью gcc.

> non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type `int` to `std::byte`

```
int i = 42;
std::byte byte{i};
```

Comment: [ошибка компиляции `error: non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'std::byte' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wjry0Uf4vqqeOtXC)

Comment: @VTT clang выдаёт ошибку, а gcc нет

Comment: @VTT обновил вопрос

Comment: [ошибка компиляции в gcc `narrowing conversion of 'i' from 'int' to 'unsigned char' [-Werror=narrowing]`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dOlhyE6jLfge28ob), по-умолчанию он более толерантен, чем прочие компиляторы

Comment: @VTT другими словами, это противоречит стандарту и ошибка должна быть, то есть нужно сделать явный каст?

Comment: Да, тут необходим каст.

Comment: @VTT спасибо, хорошо. Просто "A numeric value n can be converted to a byte value using std::byte{n}, due to C++17 relaxed enum class initialization rules." [отсюда](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) сбило с толку

Comment: Однако это верное утверждение. выражение `enum class foo: char {}; foo b{3};` было невалидно без каста до C++17. Заметьте, что тут инициализация константным выражением.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тип `std::byte` определяется как

```
enum class byte : unsigned char {};
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Согласно стандарту C++17 (Draft №4714)

> (3.8) — Otherwise, if T is an enumeration with a fixed underlying type
>   (10.2), the initializer-list has a single element v, and the
>   initialization is direct-list-initialization, the object is
>   initialized with the value T(v) (8.5.1.3); if a narrowing conversion
>   is required to convert v to the underlying type of T, the program is
>   ill-formed. [ Example:

```
enum byte : unsigned char { };
byte b { 42 }; // OK
byte c = { 42 }; // error
byte d = byte{ 42 }; // OK; same value as b
byte e { -1 }; // error
```

Так как у вас используется не константное выражение при прямой инициализации

```
int i = 42;
std::byte byte{i};
```

то компилятор выдает сообщение об ошибке.

Также из этого же стандарта

> 7.4) — from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to an integer type that cannot represent all the values of the original type,
>   **except where the source is a constant expression whose value after integral promotions will fit into the target type**.

Можно было бы написать

```
const int i = 42;
std::byte byte{i};
```

Comment: Только не очень понял, что в цитате отвечает за константность инициализатора. Narrowing conversion не происходит для константного выражения по определению?

Comment: @Summoner для константного выражения компилятор может определить, происходит narrowing или нет, для неконстантного не может и если тип больше, то требуется narrowing.

Comment: @Summoner Сейчас не помню надо искать в стандарте, но можно инициализировать объект константой, если значение константы умещается в типе объекта. Тогда сужения не происходит.

Comment: @Summoner Я добавил еще одну цитату.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow спасибо, теперь всё ясно